# How to preserve accent characters with Android Paint?

Tags: android, pdf, fonts, android-canvas

I'm writing text to a PDF file using Android `Paint`, `Canvas` and `PdfDocument`, like this:

```
String title = "Marián";
Paint titlePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
titlePaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, document.getPages().size()).create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);
Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
canvas.drawText(title, 72, 72, titlePaint);
```

The problem is that a word like "Marián" comes out as "Marian." The accent character is replaced with a plain character (not changed to an empty box or question mark like I usually see with encoding problems).

Is this a limitation of the "DEFAULT" typeface I'm using? Would I need to load a custom font and use that, or is there an easier way to support accent characters (and preferably a wide range of Unicode characters)?

**Update**

This doesn't seem to be a typeface problem, because I changed the typeface from DEFAULT to a custom font that displays these characters correctly in TextViews on the screen, but the accent marks are still removed when drawing onto a canvas.

I also found an SO question about unsupported drawing operations with hardware acceleration, so I turned off hardware acceleration app-wide in the AndroidManifest, but that didn't make any difference.

**Update 2**

Sigh ... the accent characters aren't showing because I added code a while ago to strip them out, using the Normalizer object. But I didn't leave a comment explaining why that was needed, and now I don't remember. I'll have to experiment with allowing these characters back into the PDF files to find out why I did that, and then look for an alternative solution.